# Find base for $L+M$ and $L\cap M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> In complex vector space $\Bbb C^3$ there are subspaces $L$ with base $\{(1,i,1),(0,i,i)\}$and $M$ with base $\{(1+i,1,1-i),(-i,-1+3i,3i)\}$. Find base for $L+M$ and $L\cap M$.

Ok so first I checked if the vectors in both of the bases are linearly independent, which they are, so then I found the base for $L+M$ like this:

1. reduce the spanning set of $L+M$ $\{(1,i,1),(0,i,i),(1+i,1,1-i),(-i,-1+3i,3i)\}$ to the base of $L+M$

Just for practicality, let's say $a_1=(1,i,1),a_2=(0,i,i),b_1=(1+i,1,1-i),b_2=(-i,-1+3i,3i)$

$$\alpha(1,i,1)+\beta(0,i,i)=(1+i,1,1-i)$$

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha=1+i \\ 
i\alpha+i\beta=1 \\ 
\alpha+i\beta=1-i\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha=1+i \\ 
\beta=-1-2i \\ 
\beta=-2\\
\end{cases}
$$

Because $\beta$ cannot have two different values at the same time, this means that {$a_1,a_2,b_1$} are linearly independent, and, because there are 3 of them and $dim \Bbb C^3=3$, they are also the base for $L+M$.

Now, $L \cap M$. From what I understand, I have to write the vectors that I removed from the spanning set of $L+M$ (In this case that is $b_2)$, with the vectors from the base of $L+M$, right?

$$\alpha(1,i,1)+\beta(0,i,i)+\gamma(1+i,1,1-i)=(-i,-1+3i,3i)$$

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha+\gamma+i\gamma=-i \\ 
i\alpha+i\beta+\gamma=-1+3i \\ 
\alpha+i\beta+\gamma-i\gamma=3i\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha+\gamma+i\gamma=-i \\ 
i\beta+2\gamma-i\gamma=-2+3i \\ 
i\beta-2i\gamma=4i\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha+\gamma+i\gamma=-i \\ 
i\beta+2\gamma-i\gamma=-2+3i \\ 
-2\gamma-i\gamma=2+i\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$-\gamma(2+i)=2+i \Rightarrow \gamma=-1$$

$$i\beta+2(-1)-i(-1)=-2+3i \Rightarrow \beta =2$$

$$\alpha+(-1)+i(-1)=-i \Rightarrow \alpha=1$$

This means:
 $$b_2=a_1+2a_2-b_1$$

Now what? Our professor didn't really explain this well so I don't understand which of $a_1,a_2,b_1$ will be in the base.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments for $L+M=\mathbb C^3$ are fine, but not for $L\cap M$. You just showed that $\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\}$ is linear dependend because $b_2=a_1+2a_2-b_1$. But that is not surprising...

If you consider $x\in L\cap M$ you can deduce $x\in L$ and $x\in M$ therefore there exists $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2\in\mathbb C$ such that $x=\alpha_1 a_1+\alpha_2a_2$ and $x=\beta_1 b_1+\beta_2b_2$ hence
$$
\alpha_1a_1+\alpha_2a_2=\beta_1b_2+\beta_2b_2 \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1a_1+\alpha_2a_2-\beta_1b_1-\beta_2b_2=0\\
\Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1-i & i\\i & i & -1 & 1-3i\\1 & i & -1+i & -3i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
So you have to solve this system.
\begin{align*}
&\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1-i & i\\i & i & -1 & 1-3i\\1 & i & -1+i & -3i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
\Leftrightarrow &\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1-i & i\\0 & i & -2+i & 2-3i\\0 & i & 2i & -4i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
\Leftrightarrow &\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1-i & i\\0 & i & -2+i & 2-3i\\0 & 0 & 2+i & -2-i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
The short way is to use the last line which yields $(2+i)\beta_1-(2+i)\beta_2=0$ hence $\beta_1=\beta_2$ and therefore 
$$
x=\beta_1b_1+\beta_2b_2=\beta_1(b_1+b_2).
$$
You get that $L\cap M$ is 1-dimensional and the base is given by $b_1+b_2$.

But you can also go the longer way. Then you have to add a variable, lets call it $\gamma$ and we get
\begin{align*}
&\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1-i & i\\0 & i & -2+i & 2-3i\\0 & 0 & 2+i & -2-i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
\Leftrightarrow &\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1-i & i\\0 & i & -2+i & 2-3i\\0 & 0 & 2+i & -2-i\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\gamma\end{pmatrix}\\
\Leftrightarrow &\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 &0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\gamma\\2\gamma\\\gamma\\\gamma\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Finally you get
$$
x=\gamma a_1+2\gamma a_2=\gamma(a_1+2a_2) \text{ and }x=\gamma b_1+\gamma b_2=\gamma(b_1+b_2)
$$
especially $a_1+2a_2=b_1+b_2$ which is obviously true. So your intersection $L\cap M$ is spanned by $b_1+b_2$ (or also by $a_1+2a_2$).